# What could explain over 5,000,000 System.WeakReference instances on the managed heap?

Tags: .net, asp.net, clr, windbg

I have been running load tests against a production ASP.NET web application and am seeing a huge number of System.WeakReferences created on the heap. Within about 15 minutes under load managed heap memory has shot up to about 3GB and I have approximately 5,000,000 references to System.WeakReference. Performing a forced garbage collection of all generations does not release these references.

I have seen posts about the __ENCLIST helper class which if assemblies are compiled in debug can create WeakReferences to all objects which are created, at first I thought this was the problem, but have verified all deployed assemblies are built in release.

I have been using WinDbg to debug the process, here's the final few lines of `!dumpheap -stat`

```
000007fef788e0c0    39253     18510000 System.Collections.Hashtable+bucket[]

00000000021bf120    94336    151023192      Free

000007fef7887e98     5959    189838752 System.Char[]

000007fef7874390   517429    589750224 System.Object[]

000007fef78865a0  1531190   1230824112 System.String

000007fef787dab8 51723338   1655146816 System.WeakReference
```

As you can see about 1.5GB of memory has been consumed by these System.WeakReferences.

Does anyone have any idea what could be creating all these WeakReferences?

Comment: Have you tried profiling the app - some profilers will tell you which method allocated etc.. Also the WeakReferences must be held somewhere so doing a !gcroot might shed some light.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I have run !gcroot and the output is as follows

DOMAIN(000000000213D530):HANDLE(Pinned):19813f0:Root:000000017f4cf0e0(System.Object[])->

000000013f512608(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.WeakReference, mscorlib]])->

000000018f932060(System.Object[])->

00000000ffe1b1a0(System.WeakReference)


All instances lead back to a Pinned System.Object[], this object[] contains an enormous amount of other data, any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it turns out I had a System.WeakReference leak due to dynamically creating large numbers of System.Diagnostics.TraceSwitch instances, internally TraceSource/TraceSwitch allocates a WeakReference to the new TraceSource/TraceSwitch and puts the WeakReference into a list. Although the WeakReference allows the TraceSource/TraceSwitch to be garbage collected, the WeakReference itself will never be freed resulting in a memory leak.

A little more info can be found here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracesource(VS.80).aspx